# Button with different function on second click AND changes text

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle

I have two working buttons which I would like to merge into a single button that toggles the functions and text of the existing buttons. The existing buttons are:

```html
<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('layer3').style.opacity = '0'">
HIDE SHAPE</button>

<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('layer3').style.opacity = '100'">
SHOW SHAPE</button>
```

So far, I've been able to make the text change using javascript, but I can't figure out how to properly call and toggle the functions. Here's what I've got:

```js
// i'm trying to call two functions (toggleName and shapeOpacity here)

document.getElementById('ShapeButton').onclick = function(){
    toggleName(this, 'Hide Shape', "Show Shape"); shapeOpacity();
};

// the toggle name function (working)

function toggleName(el, message1, message2) {
    if (!el || !message1 || !message2) {
        return false;
    }
    var text = el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input' ? el.value : (el.textContent || el.innerText),
        newText = text == message1 ? message2 : message1;
    
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
        el.value = newText;
    }
    else {
        el.firstChild.nodeValue = newText;
    }
}

// the second click function (not working)

function shapeOpacity() {
    if ( action == 1 ) {
        $document.getElementById('layer3').style.opacity = '0';
        action = 2;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('layer3').style.opacity = '100';
        action = 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type=button value="Hide Shape" id= "ShapeButton" />
```

I'm sure I'm missing something really basic & really appreciate any help. thanks!

Comment: Are you using jquery? I found you have used $document. I guess if you use  document instead, then it should work. 
I mean document.getElementById('layer3')

Comment: I do have jquery linked. I tried using document per your suggestion but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following code works fine. Please check that you have set the id correctly for **layer3**. Also check that you have declared the the **action** var.

There is a better way to do this as you are using jQuery. But for the moment you can try the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Event Scheduler</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name= "evtForm" method="post" onsubmit="Validate()">
    <input type=button value="Hide Shape" id= "ShapeButton" />
    <div id='layer3'> This is your layer 3 I guess</div>
  </form>

  <script>
    var action = 1; //make sure you declare this
    document.getElementById('ShapeButton').onclick = function(){
      toggleName(this, 'Hide Shape', "Show Shape"); shapeOpacity();
    };

    // the toggle name function (working)

    function toggleName(el, message1, message2) {
      if (!el || !message1 || !message2) {
      return false;
    }
    var text = el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input' ? el.value : (el.textContent || el.innerText),
        newText = text == message1 ? message2 : message1;

    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
      el.value = newText;
    }
    else {
      el.firstChild.nodeValue = newText;
    }
  }


   function shapeOpacity() {
     if ( action == 1 ) {
       document.getElementById('layer3').style.opacity = '0';
       action = 2;
     } else {
       document.getElementById('layer3').style.opacity = '100';
       action = 1;
     }
   }
  </script>
 </body>

</html>
```